# Membership payment without logging in

Tags: civicontribute

I have CiviCRM running on wordpress with about 800 members. The members are mostly not computer savvy so giving them each a login is not an option.

I would like to create a form which we can direct members to so they can enter Just their name, address and membership number (We use the External ID field for this) and submit a payment via card. Would be great if it could be recorded as a contribution or even better, automatically renew their expired membership. But if that isn't possible, just a basic page to collect the info which we can then manually process the renewals in the back end.

I have tried using the same form we use for new membership signups but this gives an error that the membership number already exists in the database.

What would be the best way to achieve what we require?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: A quick, untested thought... What happens if you modify the unsupervised dedupe rule to use external id?